# JavaScript Ternary if this and that

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

how can i write JavaScript Ternary condition saying:
if this & that do X ?

I tried `${(!props.direction && props.justify) && "justify-content: " + props.justify + ";"};` but doesn't seem to work..

Comment: please add your data as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz What data?

Comment: You haven't even used the ternary operator. But you're probably looking for `this && that ? X : Y` ("if `this` and `that` return `X`, otherwise `Y`")

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell the context from the question but guessing this is inside a `style` tag, if so, I think this should be correct:

```
${(!props.direction && props.justify) ? `justify-content: ${props.justify};` : ''};
```

i.e.

```
${myCondition ? 'truthy content' : 'falsey content'}
```

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake. this actually works!

Comment: excellent, glad it works for you!